# Iterate one result at a time where a if clause is true

Tags: php

I have a condition that checks to see it the users id from the users table is the same as the user id that is attached to the post, and after that I want to attach a specific link for each post that meets that conditions with the actual posts data:

```
<?php if($post->user_id == $first):?>
                <?php foreach($code1 as $k=>$codes1): ?>
                <div class="imgSet">
                  <a href= "modify.php?1u=<?php echo $codes1->code;?>"> <!--hyperlink to edit text -->
                 <img src="img/settings.png"/> <!-- edit logo -->
                  <a/>
                </div>
                 <?php endforeach;?>
               <?php endif; ?>
```

Example:
if `$post->user_id== $first`, my code will show all the value that `$code` gets from the database, I want to show one result at a time for each posts where the `$post->user_id== $first`.

To be more specific, if I have more posts with that meet the same condition in the if clause, I want to attach to that kink the code that is specific to that posts, but my program return for each condition meet all the result from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_shift` to get the first code from the codes array. All you have to assure is that you get the codes in the same order as the posts

```
<?php
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if($post->user_id == $first) {
        $codes1 = array_shift($code1);
?>
<div class="imgSet">
    <a href="modify.php?1u=<?php echo $codes1->code;?>"> <!--hyperlink to edit text -->
        <img src="img/settings.png"/> <!-- edit logo -->
    <a/>
</div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's still the same result as before, all the results from the database in each of the posts where the condition of if is meet

Comment: What relationship is between `$codes1` and `$post`?

Comment: `codes1` is a code that is specific to each post, and `post` retreives all the data from the posts table.

Comment: If for example the `user_id == $first` and we have 3 posts that meet that condition, I wrote a function that gets the codes specific to those three posts where the `user_id` from the users table = `user_id` from the posts table, and now I have for example 3 posts from the same user that has a id of 1 and 3 codes that are specific to each post, and I want to print each code to it's specific posts.

Comment: I've edited the answer.. I don't really understand how you get the codes.. you should assign them to an array having the key the id of the post they are assigned.. doing like that you can simply use it like `$code1[$post->id]->code`